# How to display access model/viewmodel's fields programmatically in View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

**Background**

My ASP.NET MVC application allows users to create custom reports and select things like fields to display, order of fields etc. A View should be able to read those custom report configurations and display the model fields accordingly.

**Example**

1) Let's say we have a model called Person - Id, Name, Age, Address, Height.

2) Let's say the custom report configuration is in a model called CustomReportConfig - Shows only Age, Name and height (in that order).

Now, what should happen in the View is something like (assuming there exists a ViewModel that contains both Person and CustomReportConfig)

```
foreach(string fieldName in @model.ViewModel.CustomReportConfig)
    @model.ViewModel.Person.**fieldName**
```

As you notice, the fieldName part in the above code is a string variable but in Views this should be statically typed.

**Question**

Is it possible to use a variable for the **`fieldName`** part in `@model.Person.fieldName` in the above code?

Note: I understand that this can be done by if else conditions for each field or reflection or creating a generic DataTable type of object in ViewModel etc but I'm wondering it there's a better way to do it by just creating the the fieldName in @model.Person.fieldName programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps keep a list of fields / property names, and use reflection to grab the property?

Probably a neater way to do it would be to keep a list of objects that each implement some interface, and then just loop over the list.

```
foreach (IMyCustomInterface obj in @model.ViewModel.CollectionOfCustomReportConfigs) 
    @obj.ToRenderedString()
```